# Обработка и форматирование даты ввода разных вариаций python

Tags: python, дата

Немогу придумать функцию обработки даты от пользователя. Тоесть пользователь может ввести дату в разных вариациях например? 01012023, 01,01,2023, 01.01.2023, 01/01/2023 и возможно ещё что то, и надо привести всё это к 01.01.2023. Пробовал с библиотекой dateparser, но при вводе 01012023 выдаёт None.
Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть готовые библиотеки или ваши наработки.
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: `date.strftime()`?

Comment: Спасибо, но не помог.

Comment: А если введёт 010123? Мне кажется, что лучше использовать готовые виджеты Календарь, или хотя бы разделить поле для ввода на три - день, месяц, год, где проще сделать валидацию.

Comment: Или перебор всех форматов времени, как в одном из ответов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581128/how-to-format-date-string-via-multiple-formats-in-python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае вряд ли поможет какая либо библиотека. Лично я бы сделал с помощью регулярных выражений:

```py
import re;

pattern = r"(\d{2})[^0-9]?(\d{2})[^0-9]?(\d{4})";

match = re.fullmatch(pattern, "01,01,2023")
if (match):
    print(f"{match[1]}.{match[2]}.{match[3]}")
```

Ссылка на регулярку: https://regex101.com/r/NMFJAc/2

Если вы хотите больше форматов, то напишите, обновлю регулярку

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь быстрый и чёткий ответ! То что надо. Какой интересный инструмент по регуляркам вы мне подсказали. Спасибо!